# Move snackbar above the bottom bar

Tags: android, layout, android-snackbar, snackbar

I am facing some problems with new bottom bar.
I can't force to move the snackbar above the bottom bar (this is how design guideline told me should be https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs).

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_activity"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my app_bar_main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="test.tab_activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyAppTheme.NoActionBar.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The snackbar in main_activity.java looks like this

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_content), "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

[image: Wrong...snackbar should be above bottom bar]

Comment: Share your full layout file. Your layout file is not complete .

Comment: Edited my Question. Thought, it is not needed.

Comment: You want to place snackbar above bottombar ?

Comment: Yes, like the design guidelines from google.

Comment: Note: If you're displaying a Snackbar in a Fragment, ensure you are not using com.android.support:design:23.0.1. This version has bugs, like making the Snackbar overlap the black navigation bar in landscape mode; or showing the snackbar as [semi-transparent](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/issues/1124).

Comment: its working.thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

replace your xml ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="test.tab_activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/placeSnackBar">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and The Snackbar code will be

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.placeSnackBar), "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: i am facing the problem, that my layout of my fragment is hidden, when i use the method from you. My layout is just somewhere, where i can not see it. Any ideas? It is maybe new question, but it has something to do with your answer.

Comment: You mean the Viewpager?

Comment: Yes, the viewpager is moved (to the top probably?). So i don't see my layout if i use coordinatorlayout there.

Comment: doesn't work for me . I have a tablayout inside the root coordinator layout and trying to show the snackbar above the bottom tablayout.

Comment: This is indeed a very good answer, just pass nested coordinator-layout view to make() method of snackbar and snack bar will start showing from there.

Answer (score 81):

With the material components library you can use the [**`setAnchorView`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md#anchoring-a-snackbar) method to make a `Snackbar` appear above a specific view.

In your case if you are using a `BottomAppBar` and a fab, you should define the **fab** in the `setAanchorView`. 
Something like:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Snackbar over BottomAppBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setAnchorView(fab);
```

The result:

[image]

With a `BottomNavigationView` you can define it as anchorView:

```
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"Snackbar over BottomNav",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.setAnchorView(bottomNavigationView);
    snackbar.show();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Cool. Work for me.

Comment: @Wladislaw Can you please mark this as the accepted answer? It's the right way to do it. And thanks a lot Gabriele!

Comment: This is the best answer out of all of them

Comment: Best answer. Was looking for this for a day!

Comment: How can I use this approach when the bottomNavigationBar is not in the class that creates the SnackBar? I use a single activity multiple fragments approach and the bottonNaviationBar is in the view binding of the single activity while the Snackbar is called from a Fragment (via a normal Java class that is not a View class, thus I can't use findViewByID).

Comment: Is it possible to pass the snackbar behind the menu? Giving the feeling that it is starting from the top of the menu?

Answer (score 47):

You can do this programmatically without cluttering your xml with extra CoordinatorLayouts by changing the snackbar's margins.

Java example:

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), 
    "Your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) 
    snack.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomBar.height);
snack.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
snack.show();
```

Kotlin single line:

```
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Your message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).apply {view.layoutParams = (view.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams).apply {setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomBar.height)}}.show()
```

Comment: I have similar approach, just use bottomMargin of snackbar layout params http://stackoverflow.com/a/40686399/3304280

Comment: in my case it works, but the snack slides over the bottom bar, not behind it.

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil It slides over because your view at the bottom has a lower elevation / Z-property. Snackbar's have an elevation of 6dp. Increase your view's elevation by setting the elevation property higher than 6dp in XML or a stateListAnimator. See [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view) for working with property values animation and visit [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android) for elevations.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 45):

Assuming your are working with CoordinatorLayout you can modify the Snackbar's layoutparams before calling show().  By setting the anchorId and anchorGravity the snackBar will display above the bottom nav bar:

```
val layoutParams = snackbar.view.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
layoutParams.anchorId = R.id.navigation //Id for your bottomNavBar or TabLayout
layoutParams.anchorGravity = Gravity.TOP
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP
snackbar.view.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer, it's a very elegant solution.

Comment: This is the recommended solution [by Google on Material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbar/#anchoring-a-snackbar)

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I agree that it should be the accepted answer too.

Comment: The [recommended solution](https://material.io/components/snackbars/android#using-snackbars) mentioned above indeed suggests `.setAnchorView(...)`

Answer (score 16):

There is great article about how to use it [HERE](https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e). There you will know how to make snackbar above `BottomNavigationBar`

Basically the code below presents most common usage of `Toolbar` together with `BottomNavigationBar` and `FrameLayout` as Fragment container

**Important! Notice that**

1. fab button uses **anchor** to be placed correcty and **useCompactPadding** to preserve margins
2. `BottomNavigationView` uses **layout_behaviour** to handle scrolling and SnackBar position

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/myAppBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
           app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       />

   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
       android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
       app:layout_behavior="murt.shoppinglistapp.ui.BottomNavigationBehavior"
       android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
       />

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab_add_shopping_list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:useCompatPadding="true"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24"
       app:layout_anchor="@id/navigation_bar"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       />
   ```

Implmenetation of Behaviour don't hesitate to use that ! It's easy and friendly ;) (scrolling)

```
class BottomNavigationBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    constructor(): super()

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: BottomNavigationView,
                                 dependency: View): Boolean {
        if (dependency is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
            updateSnackbar(child, dependency)
        }
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency)
    }

    private fun updateSnackbar(child: View, snackbarLayout: Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
        if (snackbarLayout.layoutParams is CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            val params = snackbarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

            params.anchorId = child.id
            params.anchorGravity = Gravity.TOP
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
            snackbarLayout.layoutParams = params
        }
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: BottomNavigationView,
        directTargetChild: View,
        target: View,
        nestedScrollAxes: Int
    ): Boolean {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: BottomNavigationView,
        target: View,
        dx: Int,
        dy: Int,
        consumed: IntArray
    ) {
        if (dy < 0) {
            showBottomNavigationView(child)
        } else if (dy > 0) {
            hideBottomNavigationView(child)
        }
    }

    private fun hideBottomNavigationView(view: BottomNavigationView) {
        view.animate().translationY(view.height.toFloat())
    }

    private fun showBottomNavigationView(view: BottomNavigationView) {
        view.animate().translationY(0f)
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. This is how you do it!

Answer (score 16):

There is a simple way, with the new Material Design:

```
Snackbar snackbar= Snackbar.make(view, text, duration);
snackbar.setAnchorView(bottomBar);
```

So the `Snackbar` will show above the `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: I did this and it works, but the Snackbar covers the fab now.

Comment: @jajube To avoid that... You should place the fab in a ```Coordinator``` layout, and the ```view``` (passed to the ```make()``` function) should be the same ```Coordinator``` layout where you placed the fab, hope this will help you :) .. tell me the result for that.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of programmatically manipulating CoordinatorLayout parameters, I found that you can place a GuideLine (or a View, if you are not using ConstraintLayout) above which the Snackbar may be placed. I'm using 1 here to indicate 100% meaning the bottom of the parent ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
android:id="@+id/snackbar_anchor"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />
```

Use Viewbinding + this code to place the snackbar above the Guide:

```
Snackbar
        .make(containerView, alert.description, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).
        .setAnchorView(binding?.snackbarAnchor)
        .show()
```

Answer (score 6):

It can be done simply if the parent layout was Coordinator layout.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.setAnchorId(R.id.navigation); //id of the bottom navigation view
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        params.anchorGravity = Gravity.TOP;
        snackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This works perfectly for bottom nav + FAB + hide on scroll behavior 

Comment: THis is the answer if you are having theme issues where the colors you just can't get right if the snackbar is showing the same line as the bottom nav.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by Gabriele Mariotti's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332487/move-snackbar-above-the-bottom-bar#answer-58665768) here is my Kotlin solution:

```
Snackbar.make(show_snack_btn, "Yeeeaaay!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).also {
    it.anchorView = fab
}.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you must take care that the ViewGroup you are providing to the snackbar is a **CoordinatorLayout** else the snackbar would not be shown above the bottom navigation menu.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I've passed a reference to a CoordinatorLayout as the first argument for Snackbar.make() and it does not render above the bottom view footer

Answer (score 2):

I am using the BottomNavigationView and Snackbar from the design support library version 25.3.1 on target OS kitkat, lollipop and Marshmallow. On lollipop and above Snackbar is hiding behind BottomNavigationView but in Kitkat BottomNavigationView is hidden behind Snackbar.

I tried to show the Snackbar with a different approach. When the Snackbar is shown the BottomNavigationView is translated on Y-axis(scrolled down) using the **translationY property and Interpolator**. Once Snackbar is gone, the BottomNavigationView appears again with the same translationY property.

**Hiding the BottomNavigationView (towards bottom):**

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) bottomNavigationView.getLayoutParams();
bottomNavigationView.animate().translationY(bottomNavigationView.getHeight() + layoutParams.bottomMargin).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

**Showing the BottomNavigationView back on screen:**

```
bottomNavigationView.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Snackbar outerSnackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Your text", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
View view = outerSnackBar.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 150);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

For any of you that cannot use the `CoordinatorLayout`, even with the `Anchor` solution such as it seems in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853999/bottom-view-below-recyclerview-in-coordinatorlayout-on-android)

It might be helpful to know you can add a listener to the `Snackbar` and at most (if not all) views can add `layout_marginBottom` at Runtime.

From my initial testing, it seems to be working quite well.

following is my code, hopes it will help anyone

```
public class ItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConstraintLayout mBottomViewConstraintLayout;
    private int mPrevBottomPadding = 0;
    private Snackbar mSnackbar;
    private Snackbar.Callback mCallback = new Snackbar.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onShown(Snackbar sb) {
            super.onShown( sb );
            addMarginToBottomView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int event) {
            super.onDismissed( transientBottomBar, event );
            initMarginToBottomView();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //.....

        mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(
                findViewById( android.R.id.content ),
                getString( R.string.snackbar_message_undo_item_removed ),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction( getString( R.string.snackbar_action_undo ),
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mItemDao.undoDelete(  );
                            }
                        } )
                .addCallback( mCallback )
                .setDuration( Constants.SNACKBAR_DURATION_MS );
    }

    private void addMarginToBottomView() {
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomViewConstraintLayout.getLayoutParams();

        mPrevBottomPadding = layoutParams.bottomMargin;

        layoutParams.bottomMargin += mSnackbar.getView().getHeight();

        mBottomViewConstraintLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    private void initMarginToBottomView() {
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mBottomViewConstraintLayout.getLayoutParams();

        layoutParams.bottomMargin = mPrevBottomPadding;

        mBottomViewConstraintLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    private void showSnackbar() {

        mSnackbar.show();

    }
```