# How to show Snackbar above Bottombar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-snackbar, android-navigation-bar

I'm using roughike's BottomBar 2.0: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/

When I display a SnackBar, it shows up on the BottomBar itself.

I want it to be drawn above the BottomBar.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/here"
        android:background="#fff">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Three Buttons Bar"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="35sp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
                switch (tabId) {
                    case R.id.recent_item:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity), "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.favorite_item:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity), "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.location_item:
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity), "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: BottomBar Only]
[image: BottomBar hidden when SnackBar appears]

Is anything wrong with the layout file??
What am I missing??

I also checked this: [Move snackbar above the bottom bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332487/move-snackbar-above-the-bottom-bar), but it didn't help..

**EDIT:**

I tried [as Abtin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093681/5002496):

```
Snackbar.make(bottomBar, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
            app:bb_behavior="underNavbar"/>
```

Now it has become like this:

[image: Bottom Bar with extra space below]
[image: That space filled by Snackbar]

As you can see, there's this unused space below the BottomBar when I set `app:bb_behavior="underNavbar"`, which is not I want..

Answer (score 10):

With the new material design, Snackbars have a new look .. you can show snackbar above BottomBar with this line:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentView, text, duration);
snackbar.setAnchorView(bottomBar);
```

This will do the work.

Comment: This answer is correct

Answer (score 6):

You should create CoordinatorLayout in xml, from his bottom you wish will be shown SnackBar and give id of the CoordinatorLayout as id of View at fun. make of SnackBar.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewSnack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

**inside activity:**

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.viewSnack), "Text of the SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the view you pass to the snackbar.

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.contentContainer), "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the coordinator layout behavior is implemented you may have to pass the bottom bar view itself to the first argument of `Snackbar.make()`.

```
Snackbar.make(bottomBar, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The other possibility is that you are missing an attribute for `app:bb_behavior` on the bottombar widget in the layout.

Comment: Edited the question.. Pls check that

Answer (score 0):

I switched from the [Roughike's BottomBar 2.0](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/) to [Roughike's BottomBar 1.4](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/tree/v1)..

Now it's working as intended (ofcourse the code changes)..

I also tried [**AHBottomNavigation**](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation), it's cool and also working as intended..

I'm not marking this as Answer, since it doesn't answer the question ;)

Comment: How did you get it working with AHBottomNavigation? I am using it too, but the snackbar doesn't show above it, but in front of it :(

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple !
in your **activity_main.xml** declare an ID for your root layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linerMain">
```

then in *view* field of Snackbar's *make* do as bellow:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.linerMain),"name",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```