# Get Snackbar above Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

I have `activity_home_page.xml` which has a `FrameLayout` and `bottomNavigationView`.

**activity_home_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.HomePage">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout_homepage_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_Homepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_Homepage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconSize="20dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_custom"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_custom"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/homepage_navigation_menu" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `bottomNavigationBar` has multiple tabs. On click of the tabs, I am inflating one of `fragments` in `FrameLayout` of id container_Homepage in above shown activity. One of the fragment is as below:

**fragment_homepage_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout_homepage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
tools:context=".activity.HomePage">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#FF31ACF2"
    app:elevation="10dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have made common method for showing `snackbar` where pass view and message.the method is as follows:

```
public static void showSnack(String msg, View view) {
    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

I tried implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332487/move-snackbar-above-the-bottom-bar) but still getting the same. I wish to show `snackbar` above `bottomNavigationView` but I am getting

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view."
```

error when I pass `rootlayout_homepage` from `fragment_homepage_home` as parent view.

Which view should I provide to snackbar for getting `snackbar` above the `bottomNavigationView`?

Unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead of `view` in `SnakeBar`:

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), msg, ... //And the rest..
```

Also, remove:

`android.support.design` from the `TextView`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
```