# Snackbar not showing up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview, android-snackbar

So, I have a `Homepage` activity which contains `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout`. On clicking tabs of `BottomNavigationView`, I am inflating different `fragments`.  My codes are as follows:

**activity_homepage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout_homepage_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.HomePage">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_Homepage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv_Homepage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconSize="20dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_custom"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_custom"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/homepage_navigation_menu" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

One of the fragments are as follows:

**fragment_homepage_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout_homepage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.HomePage">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="#FF31ACF2"
    app:elevation="10dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I figured out to show `Snackbar` in `Fragment` code as follows:

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.test), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show;
```

But it seems that I am making some mistake. The application is not crashing, but `Snackbar` is also not showing up. I want to show `Snackbar` above the `BottomNavigationView`. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332487/move-snackbar-above-the-bottom-bar?rq=1) and trying to implement the same. Kindly let me know where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HomePageActivity

```
public CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
```

then in onCreate of activity

```
coordinatorLayout=findViewById(R.id.rootlayout_homepage_main);
```

then in your fragment

```
Snackbar.make(((HomapageActvity)getActivity()).coordinatorLayout, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **`findViewById(android.R.id.content)`**

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.placeSnackBar), "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This is the exact same code as the OP is trying to adjust/implement? Can you explain your answer, also please use the curly braces to format your codeblock.