# Move Snackbar above the bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-snackbar

Want to move my snackbar above bottomnavigationview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activityRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size"
                android:background="@color/color_primary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View style="@style/FullDivider" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_bar_item"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/blue"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/main_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.mandarine.features.security.UnlockAppInputView
        android:id="@+id/unlockAppInputView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In `MainActivity` write smth like this:

```
container?.let {
    Snackbar.make(it, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

But snackbar also display from bot of screen

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332487/move-snackbar-above-the-bottom-bar

Comment: @NileshRathod i don't use `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Use a `CoordinatorLayout`  and the `setAnchorView()` method of the `Snackbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve my problem with next solution:

```
private fun showNetworkMessage(isConnected: Boolean) {
    if (!isConnected) {
        val snack = Snackbar.make(
            findViewById(R.id.container),
            this.getText(R.string.warning_no_internet_connection), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
        )
        val params = snack.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, this.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.action_bar_size).toInt())
        snack.view.layoutParams = params
        snack.show()
    }
}
```

Where u can see i didn't use `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Add one Layout above BottomNavigationView

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/myLayout"
 android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

then in Java code use:

```
final View viewPos = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);    
Snackbar.make(viewPos, R.string.snackbar_text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_undo, showListener)
                            .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is in [findSuitableParent](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/b58d3481c3619ca1e944f8c69e53418383489d2e/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar.java#L219) function. As you can see on 232 line your container used as fallback, but then root view is found. Try to change your container to CoordinatorLayout and it will fix the issue.