# bottom view below RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout on android

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

I switched from ConstraintLayout to CoordinatorLayout to avoid snackbar overlapping with my bottom view. While it worked very well in a screen with only a toolbar, RecyclerView and Floating button, in the second screen i am having a really hard time to add a view below the RecyclerView while avoiding it being overlapped with the RecyclerView

My best solution yet (below) was to add `paddingBottom`attribute of about `80dp`to the recyclerView. This looks like it solves the problem but when the snackbar is UP, the bottom view `android:id="@+id/item_cl_add"` again will overlap with the recyclerView. Of course, i can add more `paddingBottom` to compensate the size of the snackbar, but that means i will be losing about 20dp of real estate (not a good idea).

I checked many websites but could not find an simple solution

bellow is my latest code which still overlaps on snackbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_col_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".item.ItemActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/item_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_cl_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/item_ac_add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="@string/item_edit_text_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_b_add"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:targetApi="o" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/item_b_add"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorForeground"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is a screenshot **without** a snackbar (**Good**)

[image]

Below is a screenshot **with** the snackbar (**not good**)

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the screenshot.?

Comment: added the screenshort

Answer (score 1):

CoordinatorLayout is similar to FrameLayout, in the sense that views can overlap freely. So paddings cannot solve the problem.

If you don't want the recycler view to overlap with the bottom view, you should wrap them both in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but please correct me if i am wrong, to avoid the snackbar overlapping the bottom view, i need to place the `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` at the LineraLayout and this will result the snackbar pushing the entire LinearLayout up behind the Toolbar and i will not see the first row until snackbar close. Is there anyway i can avoid that?

Comment: If you want to avoid that then I'd go back to the previous setup (without the Linear Layout) and add a white background to the bottom view. That way, the bottom view is pushed up by the snackbar but the recyclerview stays in place (basically, this is what you did in the second screenshot but now the background of the bottom view hides the overlap).

Comment: I also thought of that but that will still overlap the last row when snackbar UP. That is so strange as it seems all tutorials suggest using Coordinator layout to avoid snackbar overlap but no good solution for views like recyclerView overlap

Comment: Another option you can try is to leave the bottom view anchored to the bottom of the screen and make the snackbar appear over it. To achieve that you need to take the bottom view out of the CoordinatorLayout and wrap them both in a LinearLayout. But I don't know if that serves your goals.

Comment: I ended up changing back from `CoordinatorLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`. To avoid the snackbar overlaping the bottom view, i created a Callback function for the `onShown` and `onDismissed` snackbar. While the snackbar is UP, i add `layout_marginBottom` of `mSnackbar.getView().getHeight()` and then remove it. It seems to work well but i will keep testing, i mostly worried since i don't see any such approach online.